# Change pinax accounts theme

Tags: python, django, pinax

I have a Pinax accounts app,So now I want to customize the look of the default Pinax accounts app.By default it has some theme based on bootstrap I think,now I want to replace it with my custom theme based on 960gs.How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you want to completely replace the bootstrap-based theme, you can remove pinax_theme_bootstrap from your INSTALLED_APPS and create your own templates. However, you most likely would want to just use pinax's theme for most templates and just customize the few that needs customizing, then just leave pinax_bootstrap_theme as it is and copy the template files from your site-packages/pinax_theme_bootstrap/templates/ directory to your own PROJECT_PATH/templates/ directory and customize it.

The templates that pinax provides for account app:

```
$ ls ../env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pinax_theme_bootstrap/templates/account/ 
base.html             password_delete_done.html       password_set.html
email.html            password_delete.html            signup.html
language_change.html  password_reset_done.html        _signup_sidebar.html
login.html            password_reset_from_key.html    _terms.html
_login_sidebar.html   password_reset.html             timezone_change.html
logout.html           password_reset_key_message.txt  verification_sent.html
password_change.html  password_reset_message.txt
```

just copy one of those files to your own /templates/ directory for customizing.

Comment: Then how can I use those copied templates.I meant should I write views for serving those templates?

Comment: @RajatSaxena: No, because your /template/ directory has a higher priority than pinax_theme_bootstrap's template directory, templates with the same name in the same directory structure will override pinax's template. So, for example, if you copy ../env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pinax_theme_bootstrap/templates/account/signup.html to PROJECT_PATH/templates/account/signup.html, then django will use your template instead of pinax's one when pinax is searching for its templates. You shouldn't need to write views unless you want to add new context variables or other view logic.